# File Upload path needed

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I am trying to save only the path of a file using fileupload . On clicking the button I want only the complete path that the user has selected into the file upload to be stored into the database. Just for testing purposes I am using labels in the code below but ultimately I will connect it to a data base.I only need to store the path selected by the user and not the file.

HTML

C# that I have been trying but not working

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string g = FileUpload1.FileName;

      string b =Convert.ToString(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream);

      //string filepath = Path.GetFullPath(FileUpload1.FileName.toString());

      Label1.Text = g;
      Label2.Text =b;

    }
```

Comment: Does Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName); give you what you need?

Comment: it gives me only the filename. I need the path.

Comment: I think this is not possible for security reasons. 
Some browsers (like IE6) may give you the full client path, but most of them will give you only the filename. Opera will give you c:\fakepath for instance. 
You should probably revise your logic.

Comment: The problem is it is a working system and video files are already present in the archive. What if I just provide a plain text box and he copies and pastes the url into it will that work??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code as below:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string g = Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName);

      string b =Convert.ToString(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream);

      //string filepath = Path.GetFullPath(FileUpload1.FileName.toString());

      Label1.Text = g;
      Label2.Text =b;

    }
```

Comment: Works Great Thanks exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

You can't.
See also here: [How can I get file.path in plupload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224551/how-can-i-get-file-path-in-plupload)

If I get you correctly, this is some kind of intranet application?
If this needs to work within a closed domain, you might as well think about a desktop application instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need a path for save file? Try this:

```
this.MapPath("~")
```

or

```
this.yourUploadFile.PostedFile.SaveAs(this.MapPath("~") + "YOUR FOLDER + NAME");
```

Comment: I am not trying to save the file. What I am doing is building an archiving system where the file already exists in storage. I am building a form for the librarian to use to just link the file (already available on a NAS) to the story . So all I need is when the libratrian selects the file from the NAS I need to extract the path and stroe the path in the database

Comment: I think this is not possible. The browser wont be able to post the full path. It is to make sure the security of the client computer.

Comment: is there any other tool I can use?? as this is a requirement

Comment: use fileupload element with jquery and set real filepath to hidden field and send this in form request.

Comment: I don't know jquery. But is there any way to just use a simple text box and a button that will trigger a browse operation and fill the textbox with the selected value